# ActiveRecord's save! method is deleting my object from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I cannot figure this out for the life of me. I am using CanCan and InheritedResources. I want to delete a group, but revoke the users in the group (not delete them from the database). The revocation is done by setting `revoked` to `true` on a user. In my tests there are 2 users at the beginning, and one group.

```
class GroupsController < InheritedResources::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def destroy
    p User.all # shows the correct value, 2!

    @group.users.each do |user|
      user.revoked = true
      p User.all # still shows 2 on the first loop iteration
      user.save!
      p User.all # shows 1 on the first iteration! The user was deleted?!
    end

    super # InheritedResources call to destroy the group
end
```

Why are my users being deleted? At the end of all this, I have no group, and no users! `.save!` is not raising an exception, I have tried `if user.save` as well, and it returns true. I have tried with and without `super`, so I don't think it is anything InheritedResources related. In my group model, I have:

```
has_many :users
```

There is no `:dependent => ":destroy"`. What is going on here? I am surprised and confused that `save!` is silently deleting my records.

Comment: CanCan and InheritedResources are supposed to work with the controller. It's not clear what code you're showing. Is this your Group model? your Group Controller?

Comment: Uhh... sorry, controller, forgot to include "Controller"

Comment: Please show us the `User` model. I suspect there is a `default_scope` on it which is interfering. Your user isn't being deleted, just hidden from the default scope.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me, from the context above, why this is happening...

Try using `user.update_column :revoked, true` instead of `user.revoked = true` and `user.save!`. This will save it without callbacks, which could potentially (likely?) be interfering with something.

Comment: Still deletes the record. Is it helpful to know update_column still deletes the record?

Comment: Well, sorta, it means my hunch was wrong, and it is not callback related... You're probably gonna have to provide more information, as Ryan Bigg suggested - it may not be default scopes, but something might be happening outside of what you posted. Also, you may want to look directly at the database, to see if the items are really present, or not.